# как задать скейл чтобы он не выходи за пределы вьюпорта?

Tags: reactjs, canvas, konvajs

Всем привет, у меня создана координатная сетка с точками на ней с помощью react-konva. Вот код:

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import Grid from "./components/Grid/Grid";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);
  const [columns, setColumns] = useState(20);
  const [rows, setRows] = useState(20);

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchMockBushes = () => {
      const bushes = [];
      for (let i = 0; i < 400; i++) {
        const id = i + 1;
        const refPoint = Math.floor(Math.random() * 101);
        const x = (i % 20) + 1;
        const y = Math.floor(i / 20) + 1;
        const pos = [x, y];

        const element = { id, refPoint, pos };
        bushes.push(element);
      }

      if (bushes.length) {
        setData(bushes);
      }
    };
    fetchMockBushes();
  }, []);
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Grid bushes={data} rows={rows} columns={columns} cellSize={100} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

```js
import React, { useRef, useState } from "react";
import { Stage, Layer, Rect } from "react-konva";
import Bushes from "../Bushes/Bushes";

const Grid = ({ bushes, columns, rows, cellSize }) => {
  const [stageScale, setStageScale] = useState(1);
  const [stageX, setStageX] = useState(0);
  const [stageY, setStageY] = useState(0);
  const stageRef = useRef(null);
  const layerRef = useRef(null);
  const [searchingId, setSearchingId] = useState(null);
  const renderCells = () => {
    const cells = [];

    for (let row = 0; row < rows; row++) {
      for (let col = 0; col < columns; col++) {
        cells.push(
          <Rect
            key={`${row}-${col}`}
            x={col * cellSize}
            y={row * cellSize}
            width={cellSize}
            height={cellSize}
            stroke="black"
            opacity={0.3}
            strokeWidth={1}
          />
        );
      }
    }
    return cells;
  };
  const handleWheel = (e) => {
    e.evt.preventDefault();
    const scaleBy = 1.02;
    const stage = e.target.getStage();
    const oldScale = stage.scaleX();
    const mousePointTo = {
      x: stage.getPointerPosition().x / oldScale - stage.x() / oldScale,
      y: stage.getPointerPosition().y / oldScale - stage.y() / oldScale
    };
    const newScale = e.evt.deltaY > 0 ? oldScale * scaleBy : oldScale / scaleBy;

    setStageScale(newScale);
    setStageX(
      -(mousePointTo.x - stage.getPointerPosition().x / newScale) * newScale
    );
    setStageY(
      -(mousePointTo.y - stage.getPointerPosition().y / newScale) * newScale
    );
  };
  const handleDragEnd = (e) => {
    setStageX(e.target.x());
    setStageY(e.target.y());
  };

  const scrollToPoint = (x, y) => {
    const layer = layerRef.current;
    let searchingEl = {};
    layer.children.forEach((el) => {
      if (el.attrs.x === x && el.attrs.y === y) {
        searchingEl = el;
      }
    });

    const scrollToX = searchingEl.attrs.x;
    const scrollToY = searchingEl.attrs.y;

    setStageX(-(scrollToX / 4));
    setStageY(-(scrollToY / 2.5));
    setStageScale(0.75);
    setSearchingId(searchingEl.attrs.id);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={() => scrollToPoint(2000, 2000)} type="button">
        ScrollToPoint
      </button>
      <Stage
        width={columns * cellSize}
        height={rows * cellSize}
        draggable
        onDragEnd={handleDragEnd}
        onWheel={handleWheel}
        scaleX={stageScale}
        scaleY={stageScale}
        x={stageX}
        y={stageY}
        ref={stageRef}
      >
        <Layer>{renderCells()}</Layer>
        <Layer ref={layerRef}>
          <Bushes bushes={bushes} searchingId={searchingId} />
        </Layer>
      </Stage>
    </div>
  );
};
export default Grid;
```

```js
import React from "react";
import Bush from "../Bush/Bush";

const Bushes = React.memo(({ bushes, handleBushClick, searchingId }) => {
  return bushes.map((bush) => {
    return (
      <Bush
        handleBushClick={handleBushClick}
        key={bush.id}
        bush={bush}
        searchingId={searchingId}
      />
    );
  });
});
export default Bushes;
```

```js
import React from "react";
import { Circle } from "react-konva";
const Bush = ({ bush, handleBushClick, searchingId }) => {
  return (
    <Circle
      id={String(bush.id)}
      transformsEnabled={"position"}
      x={bush.pos[0] * 100}
      y={bush.pos[1] * 100}
      radius={10}
      width={searchingId === String(bush.id) ? 24 : 9}
      height={searchingId === String(bush.id) ? 24 : 9}
      fill={searchingId === String(bush.id) ? "rgba(96, 132, 255, 1)" : "black"}
      opacity={searchingId === String(bush.id) ? 0.9 : 0.3}
      perfectDrawEnabled={false}
      onClick={handleBushClick}
    />
  );
};
export default Bush;
```

Создана возможность поиска точек на этой сетке. Тут у меня уже реализована эта логика, по клику на кнопку scrollToPoint. Кнопка пока для тестов, там должна быть форма. Функция scrollToPoint принимает координаты точки и зумится на нее. Сетка размером 20x20 - это 400 клеток, в каждой клетке точка.[codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/condescending-wing-j8l5gy?file=/src/App.js:0-898)

Мне нужно чтобы zoom к точке происходил следующим образом, если координаты указываются, например, 2000 по x и 2000 по y, это край сетки, чтобы точка находилась примерно в нижнем правом углу вьюпорта [image: как этом изображении]. Вообщем, если точка находится на границах сетки чтобы focus не выходил за вьюпорт [image: пример].

У меня в коде примерно это реализовано моковыми значениями, но мне нужно чтобы они высчитывались, не могу сообразить как это сделать динамическим. [пример](https://codepen.io/spark25/pen/VwXvZpp). Здесь реализована похожая логика, но только зум происходит в центр элемента. Буду очень благодарен идеям и решениям, заранее спасибо))